# Japanese destination airports with lower costs? (from US airports)

Tags: air-travel, budget, japan

I didn't find a duplicate, although "[ROC to TYO - how can I reduce the cost of my flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13347/roc-to-tyo-how-can-i-reduce-the-cost-of-my-flight)" 
was helpful.  My son was accepted into a training program at the south end of Japan. He was advised to fly to Narita (Tokyo) and take a shuttle all the way down there.  I found that flights to Osaka (KIX) are typically cheaper, but I'm not sure of a way to find whether another city is lower still.  All the airports I checked near his destination were much more expensive than Tokyo.

Comment: Are you flying out of ROC? What city do you want to go to?

Comment: It'll depend on the time of year, class, airline, holidays, and luck. There's no guaranteed answer.  I suggest looking on kayak.com, otherwise trying a service like flightfox or darjeelin.com.

Comment: I started out with kayak, but there are a zillion airports in Japan.  It's almost as hard as trying to steal bitcoin by guessing someone's address.  Well, maybe not.

Comment: @AdityaSomani: Destination is on the island of Kyushu.  City he wants to fly to/from is *whatever ones reduce his costs the most*.  ROC was mentioned in the related question, but that doesn't mean it has anything to do with my son's trip.  If a $68 train ticket cuts $300 off the airfare, that's a “no-brainer.”

Comment: Have you tried http://skyscanner.net? You can put simply "Japan" in the destination field.

Comment: Thanks, @GregHewgill!  We didn't, but we will!

Comment: Prices ultimately vary based on supply and demand. Bigger airports have more passengers, and thus more flights on bigger planes, and more competition. But smaller airports may have lower landing fees or more competition from low-cost carriers, and thus be cheaper as well. And as MarkMayo noted, supply and demand are also affected by the season, cabin, fare class, and so on. So there isn't a ever a definitive "flights are cheaper into XYZ." BWI is the "cheap" airport in my area, but I fly out of "expensive" DCA and IAD 75% of the time, because I'm looking at individual flights, not averages.

Comment: @WGroleau Is your son going to Beppu by any chance?

Comment: @WGroleau Also, Is he on the east coast or the west coast. USA is a pretty big country. :/

Comment: USA is a big country, but we're in the middle. Train to Los Angeles is only $200; less than $40 to Chicago. University he's going to is four syllables starting with  'Y' but I can't remember exactly what.

Comment: I understand about the variations and all that but until Greg mentioned sky scanner, I needed to ID a few places to put into kayak or whatever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are only four airports in Japan that have direct flights to the continental US: Narita/NRT and Haneda/HND (Tokyo), Centrair/NGO (Nagoya) and Kansai/KIX (Osaka).  None are particularly close to Kyushu, and it will probably cost you well over ¥10,000 in train fares to get to your destination, unless you're going to slum it in local trains that take forever (not recommended).

Some alternatives:

1. If you fly in with any oneworld airline, you can get any connecting Japan Airlines domestic flight for ¥10,000 (~US$100) with the [Yokoso Japan](http://www.jal.co.jp/yokosojapan/) fare.  The same deal applies to Star Alliance carriers and ANA domestic flights with their [Visit Japan](http://www.ana.co.jp/wws/us/e/wws_common/fare/special/visit.html) fare.  These fares never show up in online booking engines, you need to book via a travel agent or the airline directly.
2. For major routes like Haneda-Fukuoka, Japan's low-cost carriers may offer even cheaper fares if you book in advance.  Check out [Peach](http://www.flypeach.com/home.aspx), [Vanilla](http://www.vanilla-air.com/en) and [StarFlyer](http://www.starflyer.jp/en/).  Note that the LCCs only fly to big airports, while you can use Yokoso/Visit Japan fares to go directly to *any* airport, no matter how tiny.
3. While it has no direct flights to the US, [Fukuoka Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fukuoka_Airport) (FUK) at the northern tip of Kyushu has good connections to Asia, so it might be possible to score a good fare transiting via eg. China or Korea to Fukuoka.
4. Last but not least, [Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com) is really good at digging up obscure flight combos.  Trying [New York to Beppu](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/New-York/Beppu), it suggests flying from NRT to Oita with Jetstar Japan (GK), or Asiana via Seoul to Kumamoto.
5. And skyscanner.net like Greg Hewgill said: Put in "USA to Japan" and narrow it down from that.

Comment: ANA now has a new offer (called ["Experience Japan"](http://www.ana.co.jp/wws/us/e/wws_common/promotion/experience_jp/)) which doesn't require flying to Japan on a StarAlliance carrier, and is generally less troublesome than the old one (can be booked online and up to 3 days before departure).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "direct."  There are many flights to Fukuoka from USA with only one stop that can be bought as a single ticket.

Comment: Those are not "direct", since they all require a transit outside Japan.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_flight

Comment: Actually at least one of them had the only stop *in* Japan at Narita.  Wiki definition says nothing about in or out of the country; it just says a single flight number.  I don't know whether any of those have a single flight number—ones I looked at did not.  Direct, by either definition, is irrelevant to me, anyway.

Comment: FYI: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1722/how-does-an-accepted-answer-become-unanswered